# python regex start with contains ##

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all strings in text with containing this condition with python regex:

strings which starts with [## and ends with ##]

the condition is the text in block [## (some text) ##] can include any character except ##

for excample :

asdasd  [##db.tb.hh|db.dd.cc|(0)|##] asdasdasd

want to extract [##db.tb.hh|db.dd.cc|(0)|##]

Comment: And where did your regex go wrong ?

Comment: @Rahul re.compile('##^((?!##).)*$##') or re.compile('##^((##)+)##') none of them works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with this regex: `\[##.*?##\]` [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JIRT5H/2/)

> re.compile('##^((?!##).)*$##') or re.compile('##^((##)+)##') none of them works.

**Reason:**

1. In `##^((?!##).)*$##` you are looking for whole string to be a match by using `^` and `$`. Also the negative lookahead is not useful here.
2. In `##^((##)+)##` you are again looking for match from beginning of string.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use:

```
import re
result = re.findall(r"\[##[^#]*##]", string)
```

---

[image]

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/12yNih/1)
[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/wb0qmX)